# Run Docker Container on Google Cloud Run with additional parameters

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I´m using Pupeteer (Headless Chrome) in a node.js app. This app is built in a docker image and should run on Google Cloud Run.

When I start the container locally I´ve to add additional parameters due to some limitations of headless chrome in my app:

**docker run -i --init --rm --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -p 8080:8080 eu.gcr.io//:v1**

So I need the --cap-add parameter for the application to work.
**My question: How can I tell Cloud Run to also use this parameters when starting the container?**

Comment: My guess would be that the contract with Cloud Run does not allow additional docker flags to be supplied.  For example, the --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN declares that the container is going to perform additional (privileged) admin operations.  The idea of Cloud Run is to provide serverless REST interactions where the server can scale to zero.  You may want to examine the notion of running your container within a Compute Engine where it can have more access to the VM environment.

Comment: While deploying Cloud Run, you can pass this parameter '--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN' as Container arguments.

Comment: You container is not running/managed by Docker. Cloud Run is Knative. You cannot change permissions as this affects the host's security. `--cap-add=` is not a supported option.